# netcat ouput into variable bash

Tags: sql, json, bash, parsing, netcat

Today, I would like some help to insert into a database some variables from a netcat command.
I am working on Linux, I have a SQL server on my machine. Another machine on the local network is sending me some specials Json data. 
I am trying to put into variables some informations from these data **without** parsing it from a file. Like this after i will be able to insert them in the database directly from variables)

( I mean using this:   "nc -ul 8888 > recup"       and parsing "recup" with "jq" or something else)

I tried to grep the netcat command and to get the result into variables but it didn't work.

[to see what I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJrvO.png)

Is there a solution for me to get the information of some specials fields of the Json file in real time or I will need to pass by an external file all the time?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can [pipe](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Pipes) output from `nc` to `jq`, [filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) the output to get the part of the tree that you want, [create an object or array](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#TypesandValues) containing the specific values you're ultimately interested in, and finally [assign the result to a variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002).

Answer (score 0):

something like:

nc -lk 8080 | timee=($(jq '[.rx.gwrx[0].time]')) | motee=($(jq'[.rx[0].moteeui]'))

?